# How can I check the keyboard layout for the desired language?

Tags: c#

The first thing I do is collect information about languages ​​in the system:

```
public static InputLanguage GetLanguage(string language)
{
  language = language.ToLower();
  foreach (InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages)
  {
    if (lang.LayoutName.ToLower() == language)
    {
        return lang;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Then I try to check the language or not through the function `if`

```
if(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage == GetLanguage("US"))
{
  Console.Write("English is defined!");
}
else if (InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage == GetLanguage("RUS"))
{
  Console.Write("Russian is defined!");
}
```

But language is not determined.
Tell me how to check the language?

I need to check the language so that it was `English` or `Russian` via the if(check language)function

Comment: take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441729.aspx and use these codes

Comment: @SimonPrice, Well, I used these codes but they do not work. I took an example: `es-US` and `ru` did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage.culture) property of the `InputLanguage` to find out what culture the Keyboard Layout is based on.

Then you can for example base your decision on the [`TwoLetterISOLanguageName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename) property of the `CultureInfo` which represents the Two Letter [ISO 639-1 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

```
string iso6391TwoLetterCode = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

switch(iso6391TwoLetterCode)
{
    case "ru":
        Console.WriteLine("Russian is defined!");
        break;
    case "en":
        Console.WriteLine("English is defined!");
        break;
    case "de":
        Console.WriteLine("German is defined!");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Some other language is defined!");
        break;
}
```